NS3 Ip forward with delay
I would like to implement a 3 nodes scenario, connected in a line (ie. the middle node would serve as a router).
I would like to add on the middle node a delay of the packets that are passed thru it.
I understood that I need to over write the IpForward function in the Ipv4L3Protocol class. is that the right way to do it?
I am new to NS3 , and i would appreciate any recommendations of how to do it.
It looks like a simple thing, but i am struggling here with inheritance and friend classes :(

Please provide the code you have tried so far to help diagnose the issue.
